# Load User Controls dynamically based on other control events

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a "cross section" of variables that I need to use to generate a set of user controls dynamically. In the center of the page I have a Telerik multitab/page. I have a custom tree menu and a custom menubar, based on the combination of menu input each of the tabs should load a user control relevant to that cross section of data.

For clarity, almost each tab, treeview, menubar combination needs a unique control.

My problem is that all the postback/loading happens well before the "OnMenuChanged" event triggers, so I'm one "set" of user controls behind. Even if I were to use session/viewstate they wouldn't get assigned until after I needed the value stored in them.

Currently what is happening is the default user controls are loaded in the "pageviewcreated" event, then in the onMenuItemChanged I go back and reload the user controls. It seems very inefficient and is complicating up the approach for selecting the right .ascx.

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do could you not use a placeholder control and inject your needed usercontrol into that inside of the events you're managing? Try doing something like this inside of the "OnMenuSelected" event.

```
 WebUserControl1 uc = (WebUserControl1) Page.LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx"); 
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Comment: just remember on your aspx page, you have to have a placeholder control where you want the user control to get loaded at.

Comment: After looking at the preexisting code the prior programmer used tabpageview.controls.add(userCtrl); He's still having to load the controls twice on a postback, there as suggested, but he also still loads the defualts on the tabstrip pageview created